# Nodejs Puppeteer load page content very slow on AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, web-crawler, puppeteer

I using puppeteer to crawl data from 1 page by code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
const content = await page.content();
await browser.close();
```

When I run it on local, this code get full content page and time get content page about 1-3 second.

But, when I deploy code to EC2 AWS, this code can not get full content page (missing almost of html).
I resolved by add slowMo: 1000

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    slowMo: 1000,
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
const content = await page.content();
await browser.close();
```

However, it's run very very slow, about 25-30 second.

I don't know why. can anyone help me explain/fix this problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you opening/closing the browser each time you loop?

Comment: Initial startup is expensive on those low resource machines, it can take several seconds for the browser to even load up and when it does, the site can load anywhere from your 1-3 seconds.

Comment: I only opening/closing once time. I using free trial EC2 AWS 1 year.

Comment: So in your case it's going to hurt each time you open puppet, if you ever re-use it that's where you can avoid this slow down but in your case there's no way to improve this unless you can use Fetch or another grabber method.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still trying to once more time to make it better.